# MPU6050 acceleration values not 16-bit?

Tags: sensors, c, accelerometer

I'm looking at the little code snippet from [this](http://www.circuitmagic.com/arduino/control-dc-motor-cwccw-with-mpu-6050-gyroaccelerometer-arduino/) (many other projects also use similar code):

```
void loop(){
 mpu.getMotion6(&ax, &ay, &az, &gx, &gy, &gz);

 ax = map(ax, -17000, 17000, -1500, 1500);
 ...
```

If my reading is correct, it's assuming the value of `ax` to be between -17000 and 17000. But isn't the value supposed to be 16-bit? If so, shouldn't the range be wider than -17000, 17000? Is the value capped?

Any thought appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The ADC for the accelerometer is 16 bit, yes. Also the data being sent out is in 16 bit format.

But what you are confusing is *resolution* and *range*.

The accelerometer can be programmed to have a sensitivity of 2g, 4g, 8g or 16g.  With it set to the least sensitive, that is 2g, the full range of -32768 to +32767 would equate to ±2g.

That's fine when you're measuring G-forces of up to 2g, but when all you are sensing is tilt then there is only 1g - the 1g the Earth exerts on it.

That 1g is half the 2g range, which is -16384 to +16363.  So round that up and give a little extra headroom to your calculations, and you get -17000 to +17000. It gives enough range in your calculations to give the full ±1g range "plus a little bit".

Comment: Very good point! So, suppose I'd like to detect when a rod rotating about the x axis is being accelerated too much (eg 1m/s^2), should I be using the accelerometer or gyro values? I'm guessing it might be gyro since accelerometer measures linear acceleration and I might want instantaneous angular accelerations?

Comment: Actually, isn't 2g the *most* rather than the least sensitive? At 2g, it could pick up more refined changes in acceleration than at 16g.

Comment: That's what I meant, yeah. Most sensitive, or least attenuated.

Answer (score 0):

No, the `map()` function does not cap it's input or output, you would
need `constrain()` for that. With `map()` alone, there is no assumption
about the range of the values, other than the calculation not
overflowing 32-bit integers. Thus,

```
ax = map(ax, -17000, 17000, -1500, 1500);
```

simply multiplies x by the ratio 1500/17000. It is mathematically
equivalent to

```
ax = map(ax, 0, 34, 0, 3);
```

or to

```
ax = ax * 3L / 34;
```

C.f. the [documentation of `map()`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Map).